# Using Cordova/Phonegap to save an image taken from the phone camera Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, camera, save

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the Windows Phone 7 Emulator in order to create an app which allows the user to take a photo and then save it into a folder on the file system and also create a reference of it on the database so as all of the images on the database can be displayed on the app.  I can't however save the Image that is taken by the camera, I have spent ages looking through the Cordova docs and other websites.  It looks as if I need the file location of the image taken by the camera but I cannot get the consol.log to open, I have been through my Registry Editor and I cannot get it to display.  I would love an example which would show me how to get the camera image and either save it to localstorage or create a copy in order to save it into a folder.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use FILE_URI for Camera.DestinationType option. It will make the image captured stored in the device's image gallery.

Reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions